# Django mariadb error (1045, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I am trying to connect my django application to mariadb, but getting error

> OperationalError at /blog/
>
> (1045, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)")

Here are the relevent settings I am using:

```
[settings.py]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testdatabase',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

I used the following query to create DB user:

```
[Logged in as root]

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdatabase.* to 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbpass';

MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

What am I missing here? It works fine when using `root` user to connect to database (I am messing up user privileges in some way). If someone could correct me?

Note: I am able to login as `myuser` from terminal successfully. This command works fine.

```
$ mysql -u myuser -p <password on prompt>
```

Comment: How do you log in with myuser from terminal? Can you edit your question and add that?

Comment: @LajosArpad done.

Comment: Is settings.py successfully applied?

Comment: Yes I think so. I have set `DEBUG=True` and can see the database variables in stack trace.

Comment: Can you connect without the line 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',?